# Can a druid trade an existing animal companion for a feat or something?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, ranger, animal-companions

A player wants a druid or ranger alternative class feature or special ability that would allow his PC to dismiss his animal companion to get something else of similar value.

The player would really like to get rid of his animal companion to get a feat. Is there anything official that allows something like this? Is there even a precedent that I can point to?

Comment: Correct, wants to nix the class feature in favor of a feat of (I presume) their choosing

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! I edited the question to make it clearer; I hope that's okay. (Dismissing an animal companion usually involves getting rid of a current one so that it can be replaced by a shiny new one rather than replaced with, like, a feat!) Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Got the tour in, noticed the clarifying edits. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Loner flaw in *Dragon* vol. 327 does exactly that, trading an animal companion (or familiar) for a feat. Note that flaws are an optional variant system, and that characters only get to choose up to two flaws (for up to two extra feats), usually at 1st level.

The druid has a few alternate options, though none lose *just* the animal companion, and none offer a feat:

- *Unearthed Arcana*—[druidic avenger](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#druidVariantDruidicAvenger), lose animal companion and spontaneous spellcasting in exchange for rage and fast movement.
- *Player’s Handbook II*—shapeshift variant, lose animal companion and wild shape in exchange for a more minor and simple, at-will polymorph effect.
- *Races of Eberron*–shifter druid racial substitution level, can get beast spirit instead of animal companion at 1st.

The ranger also has several options, including at least one **excellent** option:

- *Champions of Valor*—shooting star, bonus spells and improved spellcasting replaces animal companion, solid choice. Would be the best choice, except that mystic ranger from *Dragon* vol. 336 exists and is far better, so you can get improved spellcasting **and** solitary hunting (below).
- *Complete Champion*—spiritual guide, skill bonuses and 1/day *commune with nature* instead of animal companion.
- *Dragon* vol. 347—**solitary hunting**, replace animal companion with the ability to apply favored enemy bonuses to attack rolls. An excellent choice.
- *Exemplars of Evil*—celestial slayer, for evil rangers, lose animal companion and woodland stride for SR vs. good spells and a bonus on crit vs. good creatures
- *Player’s Handbook II*—distracting attack, instead of animal companion. Any enemy you attack is considered flanked for the rest of the round.

Comment: "mystic ranger from Dragon vol. 336 exists and is far better, so you can get improved spellcasting and solitary hunting (below)." - Am I missing something? I can't see mystic ranger description below...

Comment: @Mołot The “(below)” refers to solitary hunting. Mystic ranger doesn’t lose the animal companion, so it isn’t listed. If I intended to mark the mystic ranger as appearing below, I would have said “mystic ranger from *Dragon* vol. 336 (below) exists and”